# Why does this `while` loop not process all records when it changes the data?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, while-loop

I have a PHP `while` loop in a WordPress script that only seems to process half of the records it's supposed to when it modifies the data, and I'm struggling to see why this is happening.

I'm writing a WP-CLI script that will set a meta with key `reviewed` and value `1` on all comments that don't already have it. My script looks like this:

```php
class Mark_Comments_Reviewed {

    public function __invoke() {

        $limit  = 100;
        $offset = 0;

        while ( $comment_ids = $this->get_unreviewed_comments( $limit, $offset ) ) {

            array_walk(
                $comment_ids,
                function ( $comment_id ) {
                    $comment_id = (int) $comment_id;
                    $this->process_comment( $comment_id );
                }
            );

            $offset += $limit;
        }
    }

    protected function get_unreviewed_comments( int $limit, int $offset ): array {

        global $wpdb;

        return $wpdb->get_col(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT DISTINCT comments.comment_ID
                        FROM wp_comments AS comments
                        AND comments.comment_ID NOT IN (
                            SELECT meta.comment_id
                            FROM wp_commentmeta AS meta
                            WHERE meta.meta_key = 'reviewed'
                        )
                        LIMIT %d
                        OFFSET %d",
                $limit,
                $offset
            )
        );
    }

    protected function process_comment( int $comment_id ): bool {
        return ! ! update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'reviewed', (int) true );
    }

}
```

(The `wp_commentmeta` table has fields `meta_id`, `meta_key,`meta_value`and`comment_id`, and the last field relates to the ID of a comment record in the`wp_comments` table.)

I have 810 comments without the meta. When I run the script like this, it finishes having processed 410. When I replace the `$this->process_comment( $comment_id );` line with `return true`, the script "processes" all 810.

With the `process_comment` call restored, I have to run the script four times to process all 810 records.

- The first time, the script loops 6 times and processes 410 records. The database confirms 400 remain. Apart from the fact the loop finishes early, this is weird because 6 batches of 100 should be 600.
- The second time, it loops 3 times and processes 200 records, leaving 200. So it's done 200 instead of 300.
- The third time, it loops 2 times and processes 100 records, leaving 100.
- The fourth time it loops once and leaves no unchanged records.

Clearly something in the updating of the comment metas is causing the loop to finish before it should. Am I missing something obvious?

---

EDIT

I've found the script is only processing every other batch of 100 records.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaargh! It was the offset! When I remove it, the script processes all the records as intended.

The first iteration of the loop processed the first 100 records, removing them from the set of records that didn't have the meta value. This left 710. But the next iteration started from offset 100, which meant the first 100 of those 710 weren't processed. I didn't need an offset – I just needed to select the first batch of remaining records each time.

The corrected script is

```php
class Mark_Comments_Reviewed {

    public function __invoke() {

        $limit  = 100;

        while ( $comment_ids = $this->get_unreviewed_comments( $limit ) ) {
            array_walk(
                $comment_ids,
                function ( $comment_id ) {
                    $comment_id = (int) $comment_id;
                    $this->process_comment( $comment_id );
                }
            );
        }
    }

    protected function get_unreviewed_comments( int $limit ): array {

        global $wpdb;

        return $wpdb->get_col(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT DISTINCT comments.comment_ID
                    FROM wp_comments AS comments
                    AND comments.comment_ID NOT IN (
                        SELECT meta.comment_id
                        FROM wp_commentmeta AS meta
                        WHERE meta.meta_key = 'reviewed'
                    )
                    LIMIT %d"
                $limit
            )
        );
    }

    protected function process_comment( int $comment_id ): bool {
        return ! ! update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'reviewed', (int) true );
    }

}
```